What is the Sense and Syntax of this Sentence in Petrarch's De Ignorantia?
In his De Sui Ipsius et Multorum Ignorantia, Petrarch complains that some friends who came to visit him subsequently told other people that he was unlearned (indoctus, illiteratus, etc.).
He argues that this happened partly because of their envy, but also partly because of his custom of not showing off his learning and eloquence in front of friends in casual conversation. He explains his views on the subject in this paragraph (cap. IV, par. 47), the last sentence of which I find challenging.

Michi autem sermo vagus inter amicos inelaborateque sententie. Valeat
eloquentia, si tam iugi studio querenda est; indisertus malim esse,
quam solicitus semper ac tristis. Hoc proposito cum semper inter caros
ac familiares uti solitus, mee presertim facultatis conscios, tum
precipue nuper usus inter hos nostros, amica fidutia in hostilem
calumniam inadvertens incidi. Nichil enim accurate, nichil anxie, ut
quidque in animum utque ad os primum venisset prius erumpere.

Should an elliptical "dicebam/dixi" be understood with "nichil accurate, nichil anxie"?
Should the "ut ... ut" be understood temporally? "as soon as something had come to into my mind or mouth"
Should "erumpere" be read as a historical infinitive, equivalent to "erumpebat"?
Does "prius" modify "erumpere", and if so, what does it mean? Is it correct to take it elliptically, referring back to the beginning of the sentence? i.e., "before I would have had a chance to be anxious or precise"?
My current best understanding of the sentence goes something like this:
I didn't speak with any anxious precision, but whatever first occurred to my mind and mouth immediately burst out, before [I had the chance to consider it].

@Kingshorsey: What's the ref. on this?

@tony it's near the beginning of capitulum IV. In the I Tatti edition, it's paragraph 47.
